# Mounting a TV on non-load bearing wall

Tags: walls, studs

The TV is 55 inches, and weighs about 40 pounds. The wall mount I plan on using will be able to reach 2 studs. Will this be enough to support the TV? Does it make a difference if the wall is a load bearing wall or not?

Comment: don't forget that the TV is pulling downward along the wall, not sideways away from the wall, so even a single wood screw attached into the wall stud would hold up 40 pounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as the lags make it into a stud or multiple studs (presuming it is a wood frame house) if the mount is that large, any wall  should be fine. Load bearing walls are not needed for mounting a tv They ARE needed for supporting a higher floor(s) and/or roof; that is the load they are bearing.

The keys to successful wall mounting are following directions and ensuring the mount is rated strong enough for your tv.